# CSS Flexbox: 3 flex items, 2 Columns (widths equal to content) and 1 item that grows to width

Tags: css, layout, flexbox

I have 3 flex items. 2 should be sized to their content and display side-by-side. The other flex item should grow to fit this width (but no more.)

**What I want:**

[image: What I Want]

**What it Currently Looks Like:**

[image: What it currently looks like]

I was able to get close, but there is still some of the gray background showing (doesn’t seem to take the text into account).
https://codepen.io/albrechtnate/pen/abbYeYL

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  width: fit-content;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.container div:first-child {
  width: 100%;
}


/* Un-related Styles */

.setup {
  background-color: #ccc;
}
.setup div {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
}
.setup div:first-child {
  background-color: red;
}
.setup div:last-child {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container setup">
  <div>Item</div>
  <div>Item Two</div>
  <div>Item Three</div>
</div>
```

I did get it to work using CSS Grid (https://codepen.io/albrechtnate/pen/zYYWgEZ) but Grid feels like overkill for something like this. If I add a 4th item I don’t want to have to change the grid-template-columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just adding a container around all of the items except the first one and using flex to make them grow as needed.

Benefits:

1. The first item can be however long it wants and the other items will grow to match it’s width.
2. There can be an infinite amount of flex items and the first item will grow to match their combined width.

If anyone does find a method that retains these benefits without adding extra markup, please let us know!

https://codepen.io/albrechtnate/pen/YzzLzLV

```css
.container {
  background-color: #ccc;
  width: fit-content;
}

.container > div:first-child {
  background-color: blue;
}

.container .group {
  background-color: teal;
  display: flex;
}

.container .group div {
  background-color: red;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>Item</div>
  <div class="group">
    <div>Item Two</div>
    <div>Item Three</div>
  </div>
</div>

<br>

<div class="container">
  <div>Item</div>
  <div class="group">
    <div>Item Two</div>
    <div>Item Three</div>
    <div>Item Four</div>
    <div>Item Five</div>
  </div>
</div>

<br>

<div class="container">
  <div>Item - This one is super duper extra looper long.</div>
  <div class="group">
    <div>Item Two</div>
    <div>Item Three</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the other answers are missing the point that you want the first item to match the width of the other two combined, instead of stretching items 2 and 3 to fit to 100%.

Is it an option it to put items 2 and 3 in a separate container?

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  width: fit-content;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
}

.container > div:first-child {
  background-color: red;
  /*width: 100%;*/
}
.container > div:nth-child(2) {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}
.container > div:nth-child(2) > div:first-child {
  background-color: blue;
}
.container > div:nth-child(2) > div:last-child {
  background-color: green;
}

/* Un-related Styles */

.setup {
  background-color: #ccc;
}
.setup div {
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container setup">
  <div>Item</div>
  <div>
    <div>Item Two</div>
    <div>Item Three</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Exactly. Is there a way to do this without adding extra markup?

Answer (score 0):

To immediately fix your problem, you can add this rule to your CSS

```
.container div {
  width: 50%
}
```

But I don't think using grid is "overkill". Grid really shines at creating that kind of layout (combination of rows and columns), while flexbox struggles, as you have experienced yourself. Grid is not an "evolved" version of flexbox, they are both serving different purposes.

> The basic difference between CSS Grid Layout and CSS Flexbox Layout is that flexbox was designed for layout in one dimension - either a row or a column. Grid was designed for two-dimensional layout - rows, and columns at the same time.

Source : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Relationship_of_Grid_Layout

Comment: Maybe Grid is the way to go… but how would I handle an (1) unlimited number of items AND (2) the case where the 1 item’s content might be larger than the rest of the items combined: https://codepen.io/albrechtnate/pen/ZEEozEJ (This resolves issue 1 but not 2)

Answer (score 0):

No need flexbox, a simple `inline-block` configuration will do the job.

```css
.container {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size:0;
}
.container div {
  display:inline-block;
  font-size:initial;
}
.container div:first-child {
  display:block;
  width:0;
  min-width:100%;
}

/* Un-related Styles */

.setup {
  background-color: #ccc;
}
.setup div {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
}
.setup div:first-child {
  background-color: red;
}
.setup div:last-child {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container setup">
  <div>Item</div>
  <div>Item Two</div>
  <div>Item Three</div>
</div>

<div class="container setup">
  <div>a very long long text in this Item</div>
  <div>Item Two</div>
  <div>Item Three</div>
</div>
```